# Error while moving information from my SD-card, how can I fix it?

Tags: sd-card, mv

i have a 32GB Kingston microSD.

i have the following message when i try to move a dir:

```
Error while moving. There was an error getting information about the files in the folder “0”. 
Error when getting information for file '/media/victor/TEL/0/trabajo': Input/output error`
```

how can i move the contents into my desktop?

Comment: It looks like the sd could be corrupted.

Comment: ¿how can i erase all the information to use the microSD? es más facil en español

Answer (score 2):

**Probably Corrupted as Javier Rivera said**

For formatting, try to format it with the **disks** program that comes with Ubuntu, if this doesn't work, it most likely is corrupt like Javier Rivera said.